# Why the *Async naming convention for functions returning Deferreds?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Intellij has an inspection (i.e. lint check) that tells you functions that return `Deferred` should be named something ending in `Async`.

[image]

Naming conventions like these make sense to me in dynamically typed languages. But Kotlin has such a nice type-checker and ecosystem of tooling, so why rely on the convention?

Especially because Kotlin coroutines bake [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952) in, the function will probably also take a `CoroutineScope` parameter, which would serve the same visual cue at the call site:

```
suspend fun doStuff() = coroutineScope {
  doStuffAsync(this /* CoroutineScope */).await()
  //...
}
```

As a side note, I understand the inspection's message that you'd rarely want a function that returns a `Deferred` instead of a `suspend` function. That's not my question. My question assumes that you know what you're doing and you want a `Deferred`.

Answer (score 4):

To begin with, a function should almost never return a `Deferred` that comes from an `async` block. It is up to the caller to wrap some unit of work into an `async` while doing other work in the foreground, then `await` on the async result before returning, and wrap all that code in a `coroutineScope`.

The intended source of `Deferred` instances is the adaptation layer between Kotlin coroutines and 3rd-party async APIs. For such calls it does make sense to put `Async` in the name and even some Java APIs follow this convention. For example, you may have a

```
fun fetchOrder(id: String): Deferred<Order>
```

and use it as

```
val orderCancelled = fetchOrder(orderId).isCancelled
```

This code is type-safe and type-correct, it doesn't cause any compiler errors. It looks like it's fetching an order from a remote system and then checking the order status (whether it's cancelled), but what it's actually doing is getting a `Deferred<Order>` and checking whether the `Deferred` is cancelled. Because your function name is missing `Async`, this kind of error is hard to spot.

Yes, you can also request the IDE to give you the return type, but it may take a while before you even suspect what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Deferred doesn't return the actual value but is "a light-weight non-blocking future that represents a promise to provide a result later".

As you cannot see this from method name, "we name such functions with the "...Async" suffix to highlight the fact that they only start asynchronous computation and one needs to use the resulting deferred value to get the result".

So the reader of your code can instantly see that your method is not returning the actual value but additionally has to call `await()` on it.

To your second point about the `suspend` function:

Usually it's other way round, the `xyzAsync()` function calls the `suspend xyz()` function.

As functions returning `Deferred` can be called from anywhere, not only from suspend functions.